# clmfires: como juntar duas colunas (variável e covariável) de dimensões diferentes numa mesma dataframe, associadas às mesmas coordenadas?

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, dataframe, firebase-database

Estou a trabalhar com a base de dados do R `clmfires`, do pacote `spatstat`. Contém informação (variáveis + covariáveis) sobre 8488 incêndios ocorridos numa janela espaço-temporal.

```
library(spatstat)
data(clmfires)
```

A área ardida é uma das variáveis de `clmfires`, e pode ser acedida da seguinte forma:

```
burnt.area <- clmfires$marks$burnt.area
```

com

```
> length(burnt.area)
[1] 8488
```

Agora, a elevação é uma covariável, a que se pode aceder da seguinte forma:

```
elevation.100 <- clmfires.extra$clmcov100$elevation$v
```

com

```
> length(elevation.100)
[1] 10000
```

`burnt.area` e `elevation.100`  estão guardados em locais diferentes de `clmfires`, e têm tamanhos diferentes. No entanto, tanto a uma como a outra estão associadas coordenadas (x,y).

Eu quero relacionar a área ardida de cada incêndio (cada incêndio é uma linha das variáveis) com a elevação (que tem informação sobre o terreno e cujas coordenadas estão associadas aos 100x100=10000 pixeis da imagem do terreno). Para isso suponho que criar um `dataframe` seja a melhor opção. No entanto, como é que eu junto esta informação num mesmo dataframe?

Idealmente, eu queria ter algo como:

```
# x     y    burnt.area    elevation
#--------------------------------------
# x1   y1        a1          e1
# x2   y2        a2          e2
# 
#               ...
#
# x_n  y_n      a_n          e_n  (linha 8488)
```

Como faço isto?

Answer (score -2):

## Pacotes R

```
require( spatstat )
require( tibble )
require( purrr )
require( magrittr )
```

## Eventos de Fogo

```
ax  <- clmfires$x
ay  <- clmfires$y
az1 <- clmfires$marks$cause
az2 <- clmfires$marks$burnt.area
az3 <- clmfires$marks$date

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# A: Incêndios ( x, y, causa, área queimada, data )
A <- tibble( x = ax, y = ay, z1 = az1, z2 = az2, z3 = az3 )
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

A
# A tibble: 8,488 × 5
       x     y z1             z2 z3        
   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>       <dbl> <date>    
 1 325.   74.9 intentional  0.4  1998-01-07
 2 285.  305.  lightning    0    1998-01-07
 3 325.  205.  lightning    0.4  1998-01-07
 4 265.  295.  lightning    0    1998-01-07
 5  24.9 235.  other        1.05 1998-01-07
 6 115.   94.9 other        3    1998-01-08
 7 235.  175.  accident     0.1  1998-01-08
 8 245.  355.  other        0.02 1998-01-08
 9 125.  125.  accident     0.4  1998-01-09
10 245.  355.  accident     2.85 1998-01-09
# … with 8,478 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

### Variáveis covariates em Células

```
# n = 100
bx    <- (clmfires.extra$clmcov100$elevation$xcol)
by    <- (clmfires.extra$clmcov100$elevation$yrow)

# n = 8488
bzji1 <- (clmfires.extra$clmcov100$elevation$v)      # elevação
bzji2 <- (clmfires.extra$clmcov100$orientation$v)    # orientação
bzji3 <- (clmfires.extra$clmcov100$slope$v)          # inclinição
bzji4 <- (clmfires.extra$clmcov100$landuse$v)        # uso_da_terra

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# B: Elevação, orientação, inclinação, uso da terra
#
# A coordenada 'x' é explícita;
# A coordenada 'y' é representada pela compensação em 'z'
#
B <- tibble( x = bx, z1 = bzji1, z2 = bzji2, z3 = bzji3, z4 = bzji4 )
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

B

# A tibble: 100 × 5
        x z1[,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] z2[,1] z3[,1] z4[,1]   
    <dbl>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>    
 1 -0.125    330   230   388   453   584   298   258   333   552   534   726   69.9   3.80 densefor…
 2  3.88     167   223   412   456   460   209   348   379   516   712   703  182.   10.1  scrub    
 3  7.88     299   305   371   542   198   284   450   560   573   511   709  156.    5.45 scrub    
 4 11.9      205   267   422   362   338   380   400   422   658   688   630  251.    5.42 farm     
 5 15.9      267   226   161   394   272   516   465   547   730   705   564  142.    3.82 bush     
 6 19.9      208   200   434   450   347   659   490   522   575   773   711   74.7   2.76 meadow   
 7 23.9      178   231   387   532   514   626   646   628   799   744   553  326.    2.98 farm     
 8 27.9      137   249   349   537   386   584   645   751   688   658   490  142.    9.28 farm     
 9 31.9      191   241   355   399   460   513   599   662   544   554   526  166.    3.25 farm     
10 35.9      116   315   417   258   394   521   765   607   435   531   654  221.    2.83 scrub    
# … with 90 more rows, and 4 more variables: z1[12:100] <int>, z2[2:100] <dbl>, z3[2:100] <dbl>,
#   z4[2:100] <fct>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows, and `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

### Relação entre células e eventos

1. Cada evento (A) ocorreu em exatamente uma das células (B);
2. Cada célula (B) contém zero ou mais eventos (A).

Cada evento ocorreu em exatamente uma das células -- *que* célula?

#### Exemplo

1. O primeiro evento, **A[ 1, ]**, é:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 5
      x     y z1             z2 z3        
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>       <dbl> <date>    
1  325.  74.9 intentional   0.4 1998-01-07
```

2. A que célula em B as coordenadas deste evento se referem?

`A[ 1, 'x' ]` (325.0) é entre o 82º e 83º *x*

```
clmfires.extra$clmcov100$elevation$xcol[82:83]
# [1] 323.9 327.9
```

3. tambem é `A[ 1, 'y' ]` (74.9) entre o 19º e 20º *y*

```
clmfires.extra$clmcov100$elevation$yrow[19:20]
# [1] 71.88 75.88
```

4. Mas como sabemos isto?

## É necessário indexar as coordenadas

1. Os índices representam os números de passos necessários para que as coordenadas de A (x,y) excedam as ob B (também x,y)

```
# n = 100
D <- tibble(
    índice_x = ax %>% map_dbl( ~{ sum( . > bx ) } )
  , índice_y = ay %>% map_dbl( ~{ sum( . > by ) } )
)
```

2. Os índices dos eventos (D) parece com isto

```
D
#  # A tibble: 8,488 x 2
#     índice_x índice_y
#  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 82 19                         <------------ O primeiro evento
# 2 72 77
# 3 82 52
# 4 67 74
# 5 7 59

D[ 1,'índice_x' ]               #     82
D[ 1,'índice_y' ]               #     19
```

3. As coordenadas (x,y), que correspondem aos eventos

```
bx[ D[ 1,'índice_x' ][[ 1 ]]]   # bx[ 82 ]
by[ D[ 1,'índice_y' ][[ 1 ]]]   # by[ 19 ]

clmfires.extra$clmcov100$elevation$xcol[82:83]
# [1] 323.9 327.9

clmfires.extra$clmcov100$elevation$yrow[19:20]
# [1] 71.88 75.88
```

4. Lembre-se que o primeiro evento, **A[ 1, ]**, é:

```
A[ 1, ]
# # A tibble: 1 × 5
#       x     y z1             z2 z3        
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>       <dbl> <date>    
# 1  325.  74.9 intentional   0.4 1998-01-07
```

## Como podemos encontrar a célula, que diz respeito a cada evento?

```
C <- tibble(
    ix            = D$índice_x
  , iy            = D$índice_y
  , X             = bx[ D$índice_x ]
  , Y             = by[ D$índice_y ]
  , causa         = A$z1
  , área_queimada = A$z2
  , data          = A$z3
  , elevação      = B[ D$índice_x[[ 1 ]], ]$z1[ D$índice_y[[ 1 ]] ]
  , orientação    = B[ D$índice_x[[ 1 ]], ]$z2[ D$índice_y[[ 1 ]] ]
  , inclinição    = B[ D$índice_x[[ 1 ]], ]$z3[ D$índice_y[[ 1 ]] ]
  , uso_da_terra  = B[ D$índice_x[[ 1 ]], ]$z4[ D$índice_y[[ 1 ]] ]
)

C

# A tibble: 8,488 × 10
#    célula                 N     A causa    área_queimada data       elevação orien…¹ incli…² uso_d…³
#    <chr>              <int> <dbl> <fct>            <dbl> <date>        <int>   <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>  
#  1 coluna 03 linha 60     6  57.0 accident          0.9  1998-07-25      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  2 coluna 03 linha 60     6  57.0 other             0.5  1999-08-28      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  3 coluna 03 linha 60     6  57.0 other             1    2001-09-20      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  4 coluna 03 linha 60     6  57.0 accident          4    2001-10-08      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  5 coluna 03 linha 60     6  57.0 accident         50.6  2006-04-07      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  6 coluna 03 linha 60     6  57.0 accident          0.03 2007-06-25      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  7 coluna 04 linha 54     7 200   accident          0.2  2001-07-06      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  8 coluna 04 linha 54     7 200   other             6    2001-07-21      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  9 coluna 04 linha 54     7 200   accident          0.5  2002-06-13      521    237.    1.85 farm   
# 10 coluna 04 linha 54     7 200   accident        150    2003-08-07      521    237.    1.85 farm   
# # … with 8,478 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​orientação, ²​inclinição, ³​uso_da_terra
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

## Como podemos resumir a informação sobre cada célula?

```
# Índices
xy <- data.frame( x =  C$ix, y = C$iy)

# Quantidade de eventos
nrow( xy )

# Quantidade de células com dados
nrow( unique( xy ))

# Identifique cada célula para o agrupamento
C %<>%
  mutate( célula = sprintf( "coluna %02d linha %02d", xy$x, xy$y )) %>%
    arrange( célula )
    
# Calcular resumo para cada célula
C %<>%
   group_by( célula ) %>%
     mutate( N = n(), A = sum( área_queimada )) %>%
       ungroup()

# Reorganizar as colunas
C %<>%
  select( c( célula, N, A, causa, área_queimada, data, elevação, orientação, inclinição, uso_da_terra ))         

C %>%
  select( c(
    célula, N, A, elevação, orientação, inclinição, uso_da_terra
  ))  

# Verificar a soma da área_queimada for célula( 82,19 )
C %>% filter( célula == 'coluna 82 linha 19') %>% select( área_queimada) %>% sum
#[1] 418.4

eventos <- C
células <- C %>%
  select( c( célula, N, A, elevação, orientação, inclinição, uso_da_terra )) %>%
    unique
```

## Conclusão

### Os Eventos

```
 eventos
# A tibble: 8,488 × 10
#    célula                 N     A causa    área_queimada data       elevação orien…¹ incli…² uso_d…³
#    <chr>              <int> <dbl> <fct>            <dbl> <date>        <int>   <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>  
#  1 coluna 03 linha 60     6  57.0 accident          0.9  1998-07-25      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  2 coluna 03 linha 60     6  57.0 other             0.5  1999-08-28      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  3 coluna 03 linha 60     6  57.0 other             1    2001-09-20      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  4 coluna 03 linha 60     6  57.0 accident          4    2001-10-08      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  5 coluna 03 linha 60     6  57.0 accident         50.6  2006-04-07      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  6 coluna 03 linha 60     6  57.0 accident          0.03 2007-06-25      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  7 coluna 04 linha 54     7 200   accident          0.2  2001-07-06      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  8 coluna 04 linha 54     7 200   other             6    2001-07-21      521    237.    1.85 farm   
#  9 coluna 04 linha 54     7 200   accident          0.5  2002-06-13      521    237.    1.85 farm   
# 10 coluna 04 linha 54     7 200   accident        150    2003-08-07      521    237.    1.85 farm   
# # … with 8,478 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​orientação, ²​inclinição, ³​uso_da_terra
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

### As Células (as células, que experimentaram um ou mais incêndios)

```
células
# A tibble: 1,661 × 7
#    célula                 N      A elevação orientação inclinição uso_da_terra
#    <chr>              <int>  <dbl>    <int>      <dbl>      <dbl> <fct>       
#  1 coluna 03 linha 60     6  57.0       521       237.       1.85 farm        
#  2 coluna 04 linha 54     7 200         521       237.       1.85 farm        
#  3 coluna 04 linha 57    24 192.        521       237.       1.85 farm        
#  4 coluna 04 linha 60     2  80.7       521       237.       1.85 farm        
#  5 coluna 04 linha 62     7  21.5       521       237.       1.85 farm        
#  6 coluna 05 linha 55     1   1         521       237.       1.85 farm        
#  7 coluna 05 linha 61     1   9.6       521       237.       1.85 farm        
#  8 coluna 05 linha 62     1   0.15      521       237.       1.85 farm        
#  9 coluna 06 linha 60     2   8.12      521       237.       1.85 farm        
# 10 coluna 06 linha 63     2  36.2       521       237.       1.85 farm        
# # … with 1,651 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```